# Are these two statements for differentiability of $u=f(x,y)$ equivalent?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Are these two statements for differentiability of $u=f(x,y)$ equivalent ?

$$\Delta u = hf_x+kf_y + e_1h+e_2k $$

$$\Delta u = hf_x+kf_y + e\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$$

Where $e_1,e_2,e$ vanish as $h,k$ do. I believe I can derive the second from the first but not the other way around.  Please provide quick proof.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are equivalent because of the following inequalities, valid for any real $e_1,e_2,h,k$.

$$|e_1h+e_2k|\leq\sqrt{e_1^2+e_1^2}\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$$
and
$$\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}\leq |h_1|+|h_2|$$

The first one is follows from the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, and the second one is obvious.

Comment: $|h_1|+|h_2|$ in second inequality